# Rails 2.3 uniqueness validation - how can I capture the value causing the error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I'm trying to capture the value that's throwing a uniqueness error (or for that matter, any other type of built-in validation) to display it in the `:message` option. Here's what I tried (didn't work)

```
# inside the model
validate_uniqueness_of :name, :message => "#{name} has already been taken" # also tried using #{:name}
```

I could use a custom validation, but this beats the point of using something that's already integrated into AR. Any thoughts? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this interpolation technique:

```
validate_uniqueness_of :name, :message => "%{value} has already been taken"
```

The RailsGuide for [Active Record Validations and Callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#allow_nil) shows an example where `%{value}` is interpolated in a custom error message:

```
:message => "%{value} is not a valid size"
```

I looked at the [validates_each](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_each) documentation and can see the validate block is passed three properties: `|record, attr, value|`. All three can be accessed with `%{model}`, `%{attribute}` and `%{value}`.

While this is limited, since it only gives you access to three properties, thankfully that is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try self.name

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name, :message => "#{self.name} has already been taken" # also tried using #{:name}
```

Also **validate_uniqueness_of** is wrong it should be **validates_uniqueness_of**

If this not works use validate method and comment line validates_uniqueness_of

```
 def validate
    name= User.find_by_name(self.name) #Assuming User is your Model Name
    unless name.blank?
      self.errors.add :base, "#{self.name} has already been taken"
    end
 end
```

Comment: I tried your first solution (`self.name`), but it merely echoed the class' name. I know I could achieve what I want with validate, but I'm trying to see if this is possible using the original method.